# ngrx router store wrong type on RouterNavigationAction payload

Tags: angular, ngrx

I started using ngrx 4 router store and I have a method to get the router state in an effect.  I also registered a custom serializer as they have suggested.  this is my helper method where RouterStateUrl is the type I registered with router reducer state:

```
export const firstSegment = (r: RouterNavigationAction): RouterStateUrl => {
  return <RouterStateUrl>r.payload.routerState;
};
```

The problem is that the compiler complains that type RouterStateSnapshot cannot be converted to RouterStateUrl.  In run time the payload is actually RouterStateURl but I always get that error at build time.  This is how I am registering my state:

```
export interface ApplicationState {
  app: App;
  routerReducer: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
  uiState: UiState;
}
```

If you nav into the fromRouter.RouterReducerState you can see that it defaults the generic type to RouterStateSnapshot.  The compiler does not seem to know I passed in my own type.  Is there a way around this?

**Update**
I was able to get around the compile error by changing the type from RouterNavigationAction to any but I hate doing that.  So any suggestion to type it and get it to compile would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stuck on this, below is a complete general example of an ngrx router effect, without payload type errors. This is based on [this response](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/561#issuecomment-344355228) to a similar query on the ngrx GitHub repo, but I believe applies the same principle outlined by [DTing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635411/dting):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { App } from '../app/interfaces';
import { ROUTER_NAVIGATED, RouterAction } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class myEffects {
  constructor(private store$: Store<App>, private actions$: Actions) { }
  routeChange$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATED),
    map((action: RouterAction<RouterStateSnapshot>) => {
      console.log(action.payload.routerState);
      // Do your thing...
    })
  ), { dispatch: false }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RouterNavigationAction defaults to `RouterStateSnapshot`

> ```
> export type RouterNavigationAction<T = RouterStateSnapshot> = {
>   type: typeof ROUTER_NAVIGATION;
>   payload: RouterNavigationPayload<T>;
> };
> ```
>
> https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/router-store/src/router_store_module.ts#L36

Try using:

```
export const firstSegment = (r: RouterNavigationAction<RouterStateUrl>): RouterStateUrl => {
  return r.payload.routerState;
};
```